# Error in Unix Socket Communication Between Two Docker Containers using Rust and Hyper

Tags: linux, docker, sockets, rust, hyper

I’m currently working with two Docker containers: one running an Actix server and the other running a frontend application (framesurge-perseus). The Actix server binds to a Unix Domain Socket (UDS) at `/tmp/iso-uds.socket`. I’ve created a shared volume for this socket, which I’ve successfully accessed and tested from a different container using netcat.

However, I’m encountering an issue when the frontend container tries to fetch data from the shared volume inside the docker container. Specifically, it throws the following error:

```
Running `dist/target_engine/release/front`
451.5 Error: render function 'build_state' in template '' failed (cause: Server(None))
451.5
451.5 Caused by:
451.5   Hyper error: Hyper error: error trying to connect: No such file or directory (os error 2)
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c perseus deploy" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

Here’s the relevant code that fetches data from the server via the socket path which returned an error:

```rust
use hyper::{body::HttpBody, Client};
use hyperlocal::{UnixClientExt, Uri};
use serde::{de::DeserializeOwned, Deserialize, Serialize};
use tokio::io::{self, AsyncWrite as _};
use perseus::prelude::*;

use std::io::stdout;
use std::error::Error;

pub static SOCKET_ADDR: &str = "/tmp/iso-uds.socket";

#[cfg(engine)]
pub async fn client_request<T: DeserializeOwned>(path: String) -> Result<T, hyper::Error> {
    use crate::SOCKET_ADDR;
    use hyper::body::HttpBody;
    use hyperlocal::UnixClientExt;
    let url = hyperlocal::Uri::new(SOCKET_ADDR, &path).into();

    let client = hyper::Client::unix();

    let mut response = client.get(url).await?;
    let mut bytes = Vec::default();
    while let Some(next) = response.data().await {
        let chunk = next?;
        bytes.extend(chunk);
    }
    let bres = String::from_utf8(bytes).unwrap();
    let res: T = serde_json::from_str(&bres).expect("Could not deserialize input");

    Ok(res)
}

#[engine_only_fn]
async fn get_build_state(
    _info: StateGeneratorInfo<()>,
) -> Result<IndexPageState, BlamedError<httpreq::MyError>> {
    use crate::httpreq;
    let body = perseus::utils::cache_fallible_res(
        "index",
        || async {
            let path = "/views/news/3";
            // let res = httpreq::request_client::<Vec<ContentViews>>(path.to_string()).await?;
            let res = future::timeout(
                Duration::from_secs(5),
                httpreq::request_client::<Vec<ContentViews>>(path.to_string()),
            )
            .await?;
            Ok::<Vec<ContentViews>, httpreq::MyError>(res.expect("REASON"))
        },
        true,
    )
    .await?;

    Ok(IndexPageState { contents: body })
}
```

Interestingly, when I call the `request_client` function directly in `main()`, it works as expected:

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let path = "/views/news/3";
    let cnt = client_request::<Vec<ContentViews>>(path.to_string()).await?;
    println!("{:#?}", cnt);

    Ok(())
}
```

I have also attached my docker-compose file containing the socket shared socket volume used by the server and front end.

```
version: "3"
services:
  front:
    build:
      context: .
    user: "1000:1000"
    volumes:
      - mysocket:/tmp:rw
      - ./static/:/app/static/
    ports:
      - 4401:4401
    expose:
      - "4401"
networks:
  default:
    name: mynet
    external: true
volumes:
  mysocket:
    external: true
```

I’m unsure why the frontend container is unable to fetch data from the shared volume. Any insights or suggestions to debug this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  In particular, if this is about your Docker setup, can you include details of how you're building and running the two containers?  The error message has a structure I might expect to see from build tools; are you trying to make this connection as part of building your image?

Comment: @DavidMaze, By default, I specified the connection being part of building the image. I don't know what other alternative to use. Normally after launch, default data from the server should be loaded to the `front` container. 
Would you want me to include my docker-compose file for the setups and volumes?

Comment: What I did is to reference the socket file in my rust file, inside the docker compose, I added the directory to the socket file.

Comment: You are using two names `iso-uds.socket` and `my-uds.socket` isn't it an issue? Can you show how `mysocket` is created and mount in another container? Can you run `docker run -it --rm -v mysocket:/tmp alpine ls -la` to show what is in this `/tmp` directory. Can you also show how did you tested it with `netcat`?

Comment: @zori, sorry, the typo on the socket name, I'm providing other details shortly